# How to make pop-up for error bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make pop-up message for error. Currently the error message is displayed in the website content. How can I make it in pop-up?

Here is the current code:

```
  <div class="alert alert-danger display-none" id="add-item-error">

            </div>
```

Comment: have look at the following link http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php

Comment: I have tryed a few tutorials but I didn't succeed, so if someone could give me an example with the code I've spoted will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the following code to view the popup. Use your css for the styling

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add-item-error").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Remember to put the code after adding the required jquery files.